# R Tooltip Data Point

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, rcharts

I have a question related to **R** Shiny.
So I want to have the tooltip which can show the concrete information of a data point when I put my mouse on the point.
Anyone has ideas how to do it?

Sample codes are more than welcomed.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at rCharts http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/. The first example seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: All js libraries with rCharts support tooltips. You may also want to take a look at [SVGAnnotation](http://www.omegahat.org/SVGAnnotation/) that allows tooltips with grid graphics.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen this done in `rCharts` by Ramnath V, in his NYTimes graphics example. rCharts sits on top of Shiny. 
You can check out a fully reproducible and [clearly described example here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131205043654/http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsNYT/).

This piece of code is what you are after:

```
require(rCharts)
p1 <- rPlot(SOG ~ yearID, data = team_data, type = 'point', 
  size = list(const = 2), color = list(const = '#888'), 
  tooltip="function(item){return item.SOG +'\n' + item.name + '\n' + item.yearID}"
)
p1$print('chart1')
```

Notice how he uses a Javascript function as an argument to tooltip for `rPlot.`

#### Another option

You can also try wrapping your element inside a `tags$div()`

Though not exactly what you are looking for, in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449252/tooltip-on-shiny-r), Joe Cheng suggests exactly that, but for UI.R. (The difference is that in that example the tool-tip is a static text.)

Say you have a `sliderInput`:

```
tags$div(title="this static text will show up in the tooltip",
    sliderInput(  # parameters here
    )
)
```

Hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: We should use `"#!function(item){return ...}!#"` with `rCharts 0.4.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can now go this with the package `ggvis` as well. See http://ggvis.rstudio.com/

This is the type of code you would use, in `server.R`:

```
library(ggvis)
df %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% layer_points() %>% 
    add_tooltip(function(x) paste0(names(x), ": ", 
                format(x), collapse = "<br />"), "hover") %>%
    bind_shiny("plot_id")
```

And then in ui.R, to place the plot you use:

```
ggvisOutput("plot_id")
```