# r - create a marker that render notes with mouse event in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm not sure whether or not there is a terminology pertaining to this functionality. I am trying to explain some special terms displayed on my shiny app and the notes will not show until we click or move the cursor to it, for example, a question mark next to the terms.

I can't find an example without keywords. It is similar to leaflet. Anyone knows what I am saying?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes what you want is a `tooltip`. See the second answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449252/tooltip-on-shiny-r

Comment: Is there still a question, or was "it's called a tooltip" the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @warmoverflow Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mike Yes it is. I'm new here. Should I close this question?

Comment: I would delete it as it is very unlikely to help anyone else and